# I cannot make my html body scroll using overflow

Tags: html, css

Here is the html and css that i am using: https://gist.github.com/zacatac26/d5733e9289be157982a448a03bda6711
this is only a single page but just making this page work is fine.

I want to make it so the header and body is always in the same place on the webpage but also have the text in the body scroll. I have tried position: fixed and overflow: scroll/auto, but when i do so the page appears how i want but the text does not scroll.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please feel free to share some code to overlook because questions having links to other destinations mostly gets ignored.

Comment: there is way too much code needed to make the webpage act like it needed to. plus i used a webpage that stackoverflow told to me to use

Comment: @zacatac Did Stack Overflow tell you to use github.com to put your code on, rather than in a snippet? Can you point to where they said that?

Answer (score 1):

Typically the best way to achieve this is just to apply the `position: fixed` CSS rule to the container of the header element. `position: fixed` removes the element from the flow, like `position: absolute`, so you need to also tell the browser where to position the container, e.g. `top: 0`. To manage the width of the header, you can use `left: 0; right: 0;` or `width: 100%`.

I think this page gives the best example of how to achieve what you are going for: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp. I'd suggest starting with the HTML/CSS templates given in the tutorial and then add the content and styles from your Gist piece by piece, reviewing the results after each change to make sure that it still looks/behaves as you expect.

Comment: that does what i need with the header, but i cannot position the body/main under the header. it overlaps. I tried using top: but it seems to have no effect

Comment: @zacatac, I suggest that you use the `padding-top` rule on the `body` element to control how far the content gets pushed down. e.g. if your header has a height of `100px`, you can add `padding-top: 120px` to the body tag. This will give `100px` for the header and `20px` for some extra spacing between the bottom of the header and the start of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make the background image part of the fixed header so that the page content would go underneath the header image and navmenu with no overlapping. I used the same percentages that enclosed the header for the background image with top:, bottom:, left: and right: